# Best "GUI" IDE when using Node with Jade/Stylus

Tags: node.js, ide, express, pug, stylus

So I come from a world of terminal windows and vi, and I created a site using Node.JS, Stylus, and Jade. The problem is now my girlfriend wants to help, however, all she has experience with is a Dreamweaver style "GUI" IDE for CSS and HTML. Is there an IDE that I can use for this? Cloud 9 is out because the project is not currently public.

Comment: Cloud9 IDE is open source. You could download it and run on your local system. https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9

Comment: @Перо I think Jackie meant the project *they* are working on is not public, therefore you have to pay for Cloud9 IDE.

Comment: @sparrow No, I understood. I am saying you can run the entire Cloud9 IDE as a local install on your own machine. Therefore you can do development locally, in Cloud9, without using the PaaS version.

Comment: @Перо Gotcha. The local version is strictly an IDE and not a solution set.

Comment: aptana studio 3 seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Windows, you can try [Microsoft WebMatrix 2](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

Answer (score 3):

[KomodoIDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) has been a great choice for me.  It has the Node.js api built into version 7, along with great interactive debugging options for stepping through code.  There are dozens of syntax colorizing options ootb, and you can create your own syntax colorizers with UDL - http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/udl.html

Unfortunately there is no stylus or jade support, however I've found that a few of the built in colorizers work pretty well for both.  And there is a 3rd party plugin for Haml - the premise of Jade available in the community downloads - http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/haml-syntax-highlighter-v but I didn't try it out.  And considering Less, SCSS and CoffeeScript were just added I'd wager that jade & stylus could very well be on their todo list.

The main reason I use Komodo is for the great vim key binding support - being an ssh/vi developer for a decade myself, this is now my prefered editor.  So it might be an option for you too :D